# Like/Dislike with jQuery AJAX returns 500 (Internal Server Error) but works when I reload the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a Like Status button that sends data using AJAX to the controller.

When I click the button, the button changes from "like" to "dislike" and all the classes and form action get changed as well.

The problem is, if I like the status, I see the changes reflected, but if I decided to dislike it without reloading the page, I get this error

> GET http://localhost/socialnet/public/likestatusCount/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)

If I reload the page and click dislike, my vote gets removed from the database and the button changes back to "like"

It works if I reload the page.

If I remove the `get()` request to retrieves the likes count, nothing happens and `console.log()` returns an empty row, I don't see any data being returned.

I opened `laravel.log` and I saw this error

> local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in C:\xampp\htdocs\socialnet\app\Http\Controllers\FeedController.php:140

which is this line in `getlikesCounter()` method

`return Response::json(['count' => StatusLikes::where('status_id', $status->id)->count()]);`

I am using Laravel 5.2

The form in the view

```
@if(\App\StatusLikes::where(['status_id' => $status->id, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id])->first())
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'FeedController@dislikeStatus', 'id' => 'dislike_form', 'class' => 'dislikeform']) !!}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs dislike" data-user="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" data-status="{{ $status->id }}" id="dislike-status">
       <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> <span class="dislike-button-text">Dislike</span> <span class="dislike-button-counter">({{ $likes_count }})</span>
    </button>
   {!! Form::close() !!}
   @else
   {!! Form::open(['action' => 'FeedController@likeStatus', 'id' => 'like_form', 'class' => 'likeform']) !!}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs like" data-user="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" data-status="{{ $status->id }}" id="like-status">
       <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <span class="like-button-text">Like</span> <span class="like-button-counter">({{ $likes_count }})</span>
      </button>
   {!! Form::close() !!}
@endif
```

The methods in the controller for like, dislike, and get likes count

```
public function likeStatus() {
    if (Input::has('like_status')) {
        $status = Input::get('like_status');
        $selectedStatus = Status::find($status);

        $selectedStatus->likes()->create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'status_id' => $status
        ]);

        $response = [
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'You have liked this status',
        ];

        return Response::json($response);
        //return redirect(route('feed'));
    }
}

public function dislikeStatus() {

    if (Input::has('dislike_status')) {
        $status = Input::get('dislike_status');
        $selectedStatus = Status::find($status);

        $selectedStatus->likes()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->delete([
            'status_id' => $status
        ]);

        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'You have disliked this status',
        );

        return Response::json($response);
        //return redirect(route('feed'));

    }
}

public function getlikesCounter($id) {
    $status = Status::find($id);
    return Response::json(['count' => StatusLikes::where('status_id', $status->id)->count()]);
}
```

The javascript form `likeform` and `dislikeform`

```
$('.likeform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var submitBtn = $(this).find('.like');
    var form = $(this).find('.likeform')
    var likeText = $(this).find('span.like-button-text');
    var likeCounter = $(this).find('span.like-button-counter');
    var status_id = submitBtn.data('status');
    var user_id = submitBtn.data('user');
    var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/socialnet/public/likeStatus',
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { like_status: status_id, user_id: user_id, _token: token },
        success: function(data) {
            submitBtn.removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-danger');
            submitBtn.find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-thumbs-up').addClass('fa-thumbs-down');
            submitBtn.closest("form").removeClass('likeform').addClass('dislikeform').attr('id', 'dislike_form').attr('action', 'http://localhost/socialnet/public/dislikeStatus');
            submitBtn.closest("form").find("input[name=like_status]").attr('name', 'dislike_status');
            submitBtn.removeClass('like').addClass('dislike');
            submitBtn.find($(".like-button-text")).removeClass('like-button-text').addClass('dislike-button-text');
            submitBtn.find($(".like-button-counter")).removeClass('like-button-counter').addClass('dislike-button-counter');
            likeText.text('Dislike');

            $.get("http://localhost/socialnet/public/likestatusCount/" + status_id, function(data) {
                likeCounter.text('(' + data.count + ')');
            });

            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});

$('.dislikeform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var submitBtn = $(this).find('.dislike');
    var form = $(this).find('.dislikeform')
    var likeText = $(this).find('span.dislike-button-text');
    var likeCounter = $(this).find('span.dislike-button-counter');
    var status_id = submitBtn.data('status');
    var user_id = submitBtn.data('user');
    var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/socialnet/public/dislikeStatus',
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { dislike_status: status_id, user_id: user_id, _token: token },
        success: function(data) {
            submitBtn.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-info');
            submitBtn.find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-thumbs-down').addClass('fa-thumbs-up');
            submitBtn.closest("form").removeClass('dislikeform').addClass('likeform').attr('id', 'like_form').attr('action', 'http://localhost/socialnet/public/likeStatus');
            submitBtn.closest("form").find("input[name=dislike_status]").attr('name', 'like_status');
            submitBtn.removeClass('dislike').addClass('like');
            submitBtn.find($(".dislike-button-text")).removeClass('dislike-button-text').addClass('like-button-text');
            submitBtn.find($(".dislike-button-counter")).removeClass('dislike-button-counter').addClass('like-button-counter');
            likeText.text('Like');

            $.get("http://localhost/socialnet/public/likestatusCount/" + status_id, function(data) {
                likeCounter.text('(' + data.count + ')');
            });

            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: if there's a `500` error, it should be in the server's logs somewhere. could you find that error message and include it in your post?

Comment: It says `Trying to get property of non-object in FeedController: like 140` which is this line `return Response::json(['count' => StatusLikes::where('status_id', $status->id)->count()]);` in `getlikesCounter()` method

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> GET http://localhost/socialnet/public/likestatusCount/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)
> ```

Means :

`status_id` is `undefined`

Because, you have :

```
        $.get("http://localhost/socialnet/public/likestatusCount/" + status_id//..
```

---

Indeed , you have `status_id` got from :

```
 var status_id = submitBtn.data('status');
```

And you have `submitBtn` is got from :

```
 var submitBtn = $(this).find('.dislike');
```

However, you change the CSS class of `submitBtn` when there is an action (like/dislike)

### Thus ,

- `.dislike` is bad selector here, you need a selector that match the button either it is like or dislike
- Assign value to `submitBtn`  & update `status_id` **just before** calling your ajax.

  ```
        $.get("http://localhost/socialnet/public/likestatusCount/" + status_id//..
  ```

Comment: I did not quite understand, and allow me to add that it goes both ways, if the status is disliked and I try to like it, I get the same 500 error. But it works perfectly if I reload the page. The data gets sent without a problem.

Comment: I tried using the button id `#like-status` and `#dislike-status` got the same error.

Comment: I did not understand your second point, I already have `data-status="{{ $status->id }}` as a unique value for the submit button and why do I need to update the status_id?